# Can you make a program run from usb without logging in to windows?

Tags: windows, operating-system, usb

Like the question says: can you put some files on a usb, that run when you plug it in to your computer?  maybe make a mini OS that you launch from bios?  I have to be able to run an exe program from it, so it would need to basicly be able to run windows, just without logging in, kinda like how you can with ubuntu on a usb with wine configured.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but BIOS needs to support this:

- BIOS must be UEFI
- BIOS boot manager should try to load from USB before HDD/SSD.

Such applications are called UEFI (shell) applications and can be created via [EDK II](http://sourceforge.net/projects/edk2/).

These apllications run at ring 0 on Intel architecture.

Comment: This wouldn't require pre- installation on the target, right?

Comment: No, UEFI is the BIOS specification used in the last 3 or so years in client machines and a little before that in servers. There are some details missing from the answer (too long) on how to actually do this, but you can Google it.